# To cut a triangle into $n$ $p$-sided polygonal regions

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

Given any triangular region and two integers $n$ and $p$ which can be large and $p > 4$. It is needed to cut the triangle into $n$ $p$-gons (e.g., cut a triangle into 10 heptagons). Among the $p$-gons, we need the maximum possible number to be convex. No other requirements on the pieces.

To our knowledge, for any high value of $n$ and $p$, it is possible to cut any triangle into $n$ $p$-gons such that $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ of the pieces are convex. Can this upper bound on the number of convex $p$-gons be raised?

**Update(31st January, 2021):** Thanks to Gerry Myerson and his comments (please see below) on some specific values of $p$. Summary:

For $p$ = 4, for any $n$, any triangle can be cut into $n$ quadrilaterals, *all* of which are convex.

For $p$ = 5, there is a neat recursive scheme that can cut a triangle into $n$ pentagonal pieces out of which only 1 is non-convex. For $p$ = 6 (hexagonal pieces), there is a somewhat similar recursive scheme that cuts a triangle into $n$ hexagons out of which only 1 is non-convex.

The question is open, as of now, for $p$ > 6.

**Note:** The basic question above can be modified with an additional equal area requirement on the pieces in which case, the question appears open for $p$ > 5. A different possibility is to replace the input triangle by a square (say).

Note added on March 23rd, 2021): This earlier discussion: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92892/is-it-possible-to-divide-a-square-into-convex-pentagons
is on a closely related question.

Comment: For any $n$, any triangle can be cut into $n$ quadrilaterals of which $n-3$ are convex.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Guess from pentagons upwards (maybe for sufficiently large p), floor(n/2) might well be a tight upper bound.

Comment: Even for pentagons you can get arbitarily large $n$ with only two non-convex. Put a small triangle, upside down, inside your starter triangle, and connect each vertex of the small triangle by a line segment to a point on the nearest edge of the starter triangle. That gives you three convex pentagons and a triangle. Now do the same to the small triangle, and iterate until you get tired. Finish off by cutting the tiny remaining triangle into two non-convex pentagons by drawing a crooked line from a vertex to the opposite side.

Comment: Thanks again for that neat construction! Still am unable to see such constructions that work from p=6 (hexagonal pieces) upwards. So, for *sufficiently large p*, we might not be able to get the number of convex pieces close to n...

Comment: I think you can still do an arbitrarily large number of convex hexagons, with only one nonconvex hexagon. It's a little harder to describe in words. starting with a triangle, draw a short line segment into the triangle from the midpoint of each side. Connect the free end of each of these short line segments to each of the others by a chain of two line segments. We now have three convex hexagons, and one nonconvex,with alternating acute and reflex angles. At each of the reflex angles, draw a short line segment pointing inward, and then connect the ends of those segments as was done (continued)

Comment: (continued) in the previous step. So now we have three more convex hexagons, and one nonconvex of the sort we just dissected. Now iterate.

Comment: Thanks! I could follow this nifty construction. It does give n-1 convex hexagons but it has the seeming limitation that the number of hexagonal pieces has to be a multiple of 3 (btw, this issue seems to apply to the pentagonal pieces construction as well). Moreover, here, we can't achieve an additional *equal area requirement on the pieces*, it seems. ...(contd)

Comment: ...Of course, in the original problem statement, the areas of pieces are not required to be equal but even if such a constraint has to be kept, the earlier quadrilateral and pentagonal pieces constructions appear to go thru - and so does the floor(n/2) convex pieces construction that appears to work for any n and p.

Comment: You can dissect a triangle into four convex pentagons and a triangle as follows: draw a small, inverted triangle inside the starter triangle, draw line segments connecting two vertices of the small triangle to the nearest sides of the starter, draw a short line segment out from the third remaining vertex of the small triangle, then connect the free end of that short line segment to the same two sides of the starter. Now by iterating this construction or the earlier pentagonal construction on the small triangle you should be able to get any number of convex pentagons of the form $3a+4b$ ....

Comment: ... (and finishing off with two nonconvex pentagons), which gives you any number of convex pentagons exceeding five.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is nothing like a complete answer to the question, but it takes care of a few cases. It summarizes the string of comments I posted.

Quadrilaterals:

Any triangle can be cut up into $n$ quadrilaterals, all of them convex, for any $n\ge3$, as follows:

Take a point in the interior of the triangle, and for each side of the triangle, draw a line segment connecting that point to that side. This cuts the triangle into three convex quadrilaterals.

Now any line segemnt connecting two opposite sides of a convex quadrilateral cuts it into two convex quadrilaterals. By iterating this construction, we cut the original triangle into $n$ convex quadrilaterals, for any $n\ge3$.

Pentagons:

Any triangle can be cut up into $n$ pentagons, all but one or two of them convex, for any $n\ge5$, except possibly $n=7$.

First, we cut a triangle up into three convex pentagons and a triangle, as follows: draw a small triangle upside down inside the given triangle, and connect each vertex of the small triangle by a line segment to the nearest edge of the given triangle.

Next, we cut up a triangle into four convex pentagons and a triangle, as follows: draw a small triangle upside down inside the given triangle, and connect two of the vertices of the small triangle by a line segment to the nearest edge of the given triangle. Draw a short line segment from the third vertex of the small triangle toward the third edge of the original triangle, and then connect the free end of this short line segment to the other two edges of the original triangle.

Now by iterating the first construction $a$ times, and the second one $b$ times, we get $3a+4b$ convex pentagons and one triangle. $3a+4b$ can be any integer three or greater, except for five. Then the remaining triangle can be cut into two pentagons by a three-segment crooked line from any vertex to the opposite side. Depending on how this three-segment line is drawn, either one pentagon will be convex, and one nonconvex, or both will be nonconvex.

Hexagons:

A given triangle can be cut up into an arbitrarily large number of convex hexagons, with only one nonconvex hexagon.

Starting with a triangle, draw a short line segment into the triangle from the midpoint of each side. Connect the free end of each of these short line segments to each of the others by a chain of two line segments, each chain bending in toward the center of the given triangle. We now have three convex hexagons, and one nonconvex, with alternating acute and reflex angles. At each of the reflex angles, draw a short line segment pointing inward, and then connect the ends of those segments as was done in the previous step. So now we have three more convex hexagons, and one nonconvex of the sort we just dissected. Now iterate.